# Nested equations with curly braces on the right

Tags: equations

I'm trying to write a nested system of equations with a curly brace on the right of each system, some text and then another curly brace which covers all other systems. However, the rightmost curly brace appears too far and too wide and \vdots goes at the opposite direction of the curly brace. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newenvironment{rcases}
{\left.\begin{aligned}}
{\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
P(x_{10},&x_{20},\ldots ,x_{n0}) \nonumber \ \\ 
&\vdots \\
P(x_{1,d+1},&x_{20},\ldots ,x_{n0})
\end{rcases}
\text{Some text}
\end{equation*}
\vdots \\ 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
P(x_{10},&x_{2d},\ldots ,x_{n0}) \nonumber \ \\
&\vdots \\
P(x_{1,d+1},&x_{2d},\ldots ,x_{n0})
\end{rcases}
\text{some text}
\end{equation*}
\end{rcases}
\text{some text}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Comment: You have two `equation*` environments nested. That's not intended to work.

Comment: Didn't you get a lot of errors with your code?

Comment: @Karlkoeller: I did! @ Manuel: It seems that it works (kind of) but not exactly what I want.

Comment: Also, I cannot make out where these errors come from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Probably this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
\begin{rcases}
P(x_{10},&x_{20},\ldots ,x_{n0}) \\ 
&\vdots \\
P(x_{1,d+1},&x_{20},\ldots ,x_{n0})
\end{rcases}
\text{Some text}\\
\mskip150mu\vdots \\
\begin{rcases}
P(x_{10},&x_{2d},\ldots ,x_{n0}) \\ 
&\vdots \\
P(x_{1,d+1},&x_{2d},\ldots ,x_{n0})
\end{rcases}
\text{some text}
\end{rcases}
\text{some text}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Note that `rcases` environment is already defined by `mathtools` and that you can't nest `equation` environments.

Comment: Yes, I want exactly this thing!

Comment: (Almost) perfect! Two things though: on my system, rcases need to be defined. But most important is that the middle \vdots appears right, just before the big curly brace.

Comment: @SotirisKal. If you are loading `mathtools`, `rcases` is defined unless you have a very old version. In this case please update your package. About the middle `\vdots` modify the value in `\mskip150mu` to your needs.

Comment: You're right! My version is too old. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement with the `alignedat` environment and the `\vdotswithin` command, from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{rcases}
\begin{rcases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
P(x_{10}&,x_{20}& ,\ldots ,x_{n0}) \\[-1.5ex]
&\vdotswithin{x_20,}&
\\[-1.25ex]
P(x_{1,d+1}&, x_{20}& ,\ldots ,x_{n0})
\end{alignedat}
\end{rcases}
\text{Some text}\\
\mskip90mu\vdots \\
\begin{rcases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
P(x_{10}&, x_{2d}&,\ldots ,x_{n0}) \\[-1.5ex]
 & \vdotswithin{x_{2d},}& \\[-1.25ex]
P(x_{1,d+1}&, x_{2d} &,\ldots ,x_{n0})
\end{alignedat}
\end{rcases}
\text{some other text}
\end{rcases}
\text{some text}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]